# Rails: confustion over relations for same model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm using this gem called [activerecord-reputation-system](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system)

I have the model `user` and I was wondering if I can do the following:

```
#/models/user.rb
 has_reputation :credits,
    :source => :user
```

which means mean letting a user vote another user.

when I do :

```
user1.add_evaluation(:credits,1,user2)
```

I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Source has already been taken
```

Answer (score 0):

A "vote" is a 'self-join' between two users. A vote is owned by both the voter and the votee, and both relationships need to be specified. This is what you are looking for: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins

Comment: Thanks, I forgot the term was called self-join. However now I'm still getting same error even after creating a join/reference table.

Comment: Can you post the code you've used to create the models, associations, and validations?